# Почему не отменяется position на медиазапросах?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Пытаюсь сделать заголовок с двумя линиями с боку, все вроде нормально, но на медиазапросах, мне нужно линии переопределить, чтоб они находились по другому, `position` почему-то не отменяется

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h2::before {
  content: "";
  width: 170px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
}

h2::after {
  content: "";
  width: 170px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  h2 {
    overflow: visible;
  }
  h2::before {
    width: 350px;
    top: -8px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -175px;
  }
  h2::after {
    width: 350px;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -175px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно переопределить свойство position переписав его свойство например на unset или relative. Если вы просто не пропишите его в медиазапросе - оно останется прежним.

Answer (score 1):

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h2::before {
  content: "";
  width: 170px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
}

h2::after {
  content: "";
  width: 170px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  h2 {
    overflow: visible;
  }
  h2::before {
    width: 350px;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -175px;
    top: -8px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  h2::after {
    width: 350px;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: 50%;
    top: auto;
    margin-left: -175px;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h2>
```

Comment: хороший пример +5 от меня